# Best practice for creating a hierarchy of dollar bracket measures in SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I have a measure for open balance for a particular account.  My users want to be able to have a hierarchy that can bucket dollar balances into something like 0-500,500-1000, etc.

Is the only way to do this by creating a dimension that defines that hierarchy.  Are there any other methods for providing this functionality to users.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it as an hierarchy your proposed way would be the best solution, yes. The dimension can be derived from the fact table with a simple SQL query such as

```
SELECT CASE WHEN balance >= 0 AND balance < 500 THEN 1 
WHEN balance >= 500 AND balance < 1000 THEN 2 END AS balanceGroupID,
CASE WHEN balance WHEN balance >= 0 AND balance < 500 THEN "0 - 500"
WHEN balance >= 500 AND balance < 1000 THEN "500 - 1000" END AS balanceGroupName
```

HTH